# Unity C# and Layar SDK Java - AndroidJavaException

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, layar

I'm Trying to Integrate Layar SDK to Unity.
But I've got some issue.

Here is the **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.layar.player"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="8.5.2" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application>
    <activity
        android:name="com.layar.sdk.LayarSDKActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.layar.player.geo.FilterSettingsActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/FilterTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.layar.LayerDetailsActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/LayarTitleTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.layar.WebActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/LayarTitleTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.layar.ShareSocialActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Layar.Theme.Default" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.layar.VideoActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/FullScreenTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.layar.AudioActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/SmartDialogTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.layar.ScreenshotActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.layar.ShareOnFacebookActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible|adjustResize" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.layar.localytics.CloseSesionBroadcastReciever"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.layar.close_session" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

and This is My c#

```
using UnityEngine;

public class IntegrationLayar : MonoBehaviour {

private AndroidJavaObject LayarSDK = null;
private AndroidJavaObject activity = null;
private AndroidJavaObject context = null;

private string oauthKey = "code";
private string oauthSecret = "code2";


void Start ()
{
        if (LayarSDK == null)
        {
            using (AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            {
                activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
                context = activity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

                //activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(runOnUiThread));
                Debug.Log("unity3D JAVA - Working");
            }

            using (AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.layar.player"))
            {
                if (pluginClass != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Layar Java - Working");
                    pluginClass.CallStatic("initialize", context, oauthKey, oauthSecret);
                    pluginClass.CallStatic("startLayarActivity", context);
                }
            }
    }
}
}
```

**Error** :

> AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.layar.player

As I understand it, it didn't found a Class named like this in the Java.
So The problem is what ? I'm calling the wrong activity?

Here is the link to Layar API [link](https://www.layar.com/documentation/layar-sdk/integrate-android-studio/)

As I see in the Layar API the class is "LayarVisionSDK".

```
AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.layar.player.LayarVisionSDK")
```

So Maybe this should work?

I certainly doing it wrong but if any of you have a direction to follow, I'll be glad to learn :)

**UPDATE 1 :**

This is from the APK

```
Class LayarVisionSDK

java.lang.Object
com.layar.sdk.LayarVisionSDK
```

So instead of using

```
AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.layar.player.LayarVisionSDK")
```

I'm using

```
AndroidJavaObject LayarVisionSDK = new AndroidJavaObject("com.layar.sdk.LayarVisionSDK");
```

But still not sucessfull. I'm asking myself if the problem may be not where it seem to be.

**UPDATE 2 :**

OK ! I found why I get this error, the API doc was not updated so i checked in the java package and found where was the "initialize" method.

So here is the new c# code.

```
using (AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.layar.sdk.LayarSDK"))
                {
                    if (pluginClass != null)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("SDK LAYAR FOUND !!! ");
                        pluginClass.CallStatic("initialize", context, oauthKey, oauthSecret);
                        Debug.Log("INITIALIZED");
                        //pluginClass.Call("startLayarActivity", context);
                    }
                }
```

**But I got a new error :**

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat;
```

Am I missing a android library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have android-support-v4.jar under a **Plugins/Android/libs** folder.

You can download the file from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0kCW_l7jop5enVpa3A3VXFDNzg).

Comment: That's what I did this night, But now I got a new Error - AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: LKotlin.Pair

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm make it work !

I just add android support lib and kotlin lib.

Thanks for your help :)